# Why I am getting error running webapi from vscode?

Tags: webapi

I created a new Web API in visual studio code by running this:

```
dotnet new webapi -n API -controllers
```

and then pressed ctrl + shift + P and typed build to generate assets for build and debug. now I have the below 2 files:

launchsettings.js and launch.js

why I am getting error when trying to run the visual studio code for new webapi.

I installed iisexpress extention and still not working.

when I run:

```
dotnet run
```

I am getting 404 error.

---

This localhost page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:5133/
HTTP ERROR 404

Comment: What do you expect to be at the root URL and why?  I would expect a strictly API project to have specific API controllers, not a home page.  Can you clarify?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I needed to specify a path in HttpGet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is the Web API, you should try requesting the exact endpoint in your webapi followed by the mentioned URL.